# Java Process only exits after a garbage collection

Tags: java, spring, garbage-collection, project-reactor

I've created an CLI application (using Spring) to read external APIs, store it in a database and process that data.

To process data I'm using project reactor (https://projectreactor.io/) to do things in parallel.

However what I'm seeing is that the java process doesn't exit when it has to do a lot of work.

What I've discovered is that the process stops when you trigger a full Garbage Collection (e.g. with `jconsole`).

So in that case it isn't some thread (created by me in the application) that's hanging or some weird deadlock, but something in the Garbage Collector.

Basically my program does something like this:

```
public class Runner {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Runner.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()) {
            run(args, context);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            logger.error("error", t);
        } finally {
            logger.info("closed application context");
        }
    }
}
```

where the `run` method triggers a lot of other code (that I think is not very relevant).

What's interesting is that `closed application context` is logged, but then nothing happens.

Some crude solution would be to call `System.gc()` and `System.exit(0)` at the end, but I'm hoping there are better (configuration) solutions?

Comment: Well, I'd guess that what `run()` triggers _is_ relevant, i.e. even if the main thread exits there could still be other live threads and hence the application is still running. Also "the process stops when you trigger a full Garbage Collection" - that's probably what you call a "stop-the-world gc".

Comment: True, that was my first idea too, but why would a GC influence that?

Comment: You are creating a AnnotationConfigApplicationContext but never close() it. Mybe it has some threads, connections or other resources left open? Possibley with soft or weak references that are wiped by full GC.

Comment: @Selaron thanks, but it is, i'm using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html. Also it works fine when my `run` has less to do...

Comment: You are right, didn't see that try(...){} also does the close().

Comment: Try debugging by adding some code at the end of your application, printing the active threads. use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#enumerate(java.lang.Thread[]) ; to get the list of threads, and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isDaemon() while you iterate to check all remainibng beside your main are daemon.

Comment: The idea is that perhaps you have 2 objects referencing each other and one of your old thread waiting for those to be destroyed.

Comment: A stop-the-world gc could lead to a number of issues, e.g. with timing (where one thread times out, waits for another and thus gets locked etc.) or with weak references and the like, i.e. the gc will remove any weak references and the threads will then fail while as long as no gc happens those references keep the threads alive. As I said it's hard to tell without knowing what's going on inside that `run()` and that might way too much for SO anyway.

Comment: Did you try to create a thread dump before calling gc but at a time where you think all the work must have been done and all the threads should be stopped? Did you analyze that thread dump to see which threads are still running and what they are doing?

Comment: Hmm, it seems I got some `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` thread running deeply in the code that wasn't closed correctly... So it was on old thread indeed!